# Is it better to calculate area of a global raster using long/lat or using an equal area projection (e.g. Galls-Peters)?

Tags: raster, coordinate-system, area, rgdal

I am trying to calculate the area of values in a global spanning raster with values of NA, 1, 2 or 3. I would like to know the total area of each category, however, the map is currently in lat long (unprojected) coordinates.

Is it better to calculate the area using the unprojected coordinates (e.g. with the `area()` function in the raster package in r) or is it better to first project the raster to a projected coordinate system (e.g. Gall's Peters) and then calculate the area?

Comment: In unprojected coordinates, you'll have square degrees as area units. The problem here is that your raster is global and I don't know how have these areas in square meters. For example, with UTM projection, you'll have to determine where your pixel belong ...

Comment: Each raster cell is a spheroidal trapezoid (except for the first and last rows, which are spheroidal triangles if the extent includes a pole). The most accurate way to do this would be to create a 64-bit float raster with the actual area for each cell, but a 32-bit raster would suffice. You'd need a vector geodesic library to compute the values.